# Both cmake and qmake usage.

Tags: c++, cmake, qmake

I have a subsystem configured with qmake (.pro file), but other subsystems are configured for building with cmake.

What I want is to run

```
cmake ... && make && make install
```

at the top level of the project and I do not want to completely rewrite CMakeLists.txt for that qmake configured subsystem.

What I've done:
I created CMakeLists.txt with given content:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(SQLiteReplication)

add_custom_target(SQLiteReplication ALL
        COMMAND qmake -o QMakefile 
        COMMAND make -f QMakefile 
      #COMMAND make -f QMakefile install
)

install(CODE "execute_process(COMMAND \"make -f QMakefile install\")")
```

The idea is to call qmake from cmake generated makefiles and it seems working fine.

The problem is in install targets. It looks like `execute_process` won't run at install time.

So, the question is what should I do in cmake to generate the install target such as

```
install: QMakefile
         make -f QMakefile install
```

Thanks.

Comment: Since CMake 2.8.11 it is possible to have CMake create the moc files so you don't need to call qmake, might this be an option?

Comment: Inner double quotes are not needed in `execute_process`. Because of them whole your command is treated as single executable, which is wrong.

Comment: This is it!!!!!

install(CODE "execute_process(COMMAND make -f QMakefile install)")

works fine!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: One of you guys should answer the question with an officially accepted answer... Removing the quotes is the correct solution.

Comment: it may be useful to use this, if qmake is at a custom location: `get_target_property (QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE Qt5::qmake IMPORTED_LOCATION)`  and then use it like this :   `COMMAND ${QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE} -o QMakefile`